# showing "Not responding" while using large data

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn, wxpython

I build an APP for classifier. I've used `wxpython` to build graphical interface. Problem occurs when I try to train classifier with large data like `13,00,000`.

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
XT = vectorizer.fit_transform(self.TrainData)   # Not responding

classifier = svm.LinearSVC()
classifier.fit(XT, self.y_train)
```

`vectorizer.fit_transform` this is actually working behind. But Window is showing not responding.

[image]

What is the problem? How can I solve this?

Comment: Does it generally take a long time anyway, without the GUI, in my experience SVM's take ages to train so this may not be unexpected

Comment: Without GUI, it takes 8 min to train. But with GUI after 5s its showing `not responding`

Comment: This sounds like something to do with the how the GUI is waiting for messages/responses does it eventually complete or not? If not you should consider some form of callback that doesn't freeze the gui and signal when the training completes

Comment: How can I do this? `form of callback` ?

Comment: That I can't help you with I don't have knowledge of wxpython but that would be how I would approach this, maybe have a look at the docs or other posts on SO about this

Answer (score 2):

Any long running process can block the GUI's main loop. I suspect that you are doing this here. When the main loop is blocked, your UI will freeze. To get around this, you should put your `fit_transform` code into a thread and run it there. When it finishes, you can use one of wxPython's thread-safe methods to tell the UI to update (i.e. `wx.CallAfter` or `wx.PostEvent`).

You can find examples of using threads and wxPython at the following:

- http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks
- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/22/wxpython-and-threads/